# Suppose that $\sum a_k$ is a divergent series in $(0,\infty)$. Show that $(f_n)\to \infty$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

> Suppose that $\sum a_k$ is a divergent series in $(0,\infty)$ such that $\sum a_k X^k$ have radius of convergence $1$. Now define
>
> $$f_n:=\sum a_k\left(1-\frac1n\right)^k;\quad n\in\Bbb N$$
>
> Prove that $(f_n)\to\infty$. HINT: use Bernoulli inequality $(1+x)^k\ge 1+kx$ for $x>-1$ to get an upper bound of the terms $1-(1-1/n)^m$.

I dont know how to do this proof. What I tried is prove it by contradiction, i.e. if $(f_n)$ converges then

$$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists N\in\Bbb N:|f_n-f_m|<\epsilon$$

Then without lose of generality suppose that $n>m$, and using Bernoulli inequality we have

$$|f_n-f_m|=\sum a_k\left|\left(1-\frac1n\right)^k-\left(1-\frac1m\right)^k\right|=\\=\sum a_k\left(\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^k-\left(1-\frac1m\right)^k\right)\le \color{red}{\sum a_k\left(\left(1-\frac1n\right)^k-1+\frac{k}{m}\right)}$$

then is obvious that the upper bound marked in red diverges, just consider $k\ge 2m$. But I dont know how to justify, from here, that $(f_n)$ diverges.

Some hint? Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Is it given that $a_k\ge0$? I am not sure what "diverges in $(0,\infty)$" means.

Comment: @robjohn I edited the title, it was not so correct before.

Comment: In my opinion, it's simpler to note that for every fixed $m$ you have $$f_n \geqslant \sum_{k = 0}^m a_k\biggl(1 - \frac{1}{n}\biggr)^k.$$ There's no problem taking the limit as $n\to\infty$ on the right hand side, giving a lower bound for $\liminf f_n$.

Comment: Right @DanielFischer... what a dumb I am xDD. I was obsessed in the complete series. Indeed the "hint" of this exercise is terrible misleading.

Comment: Well, there's that given hint. I still haven't figured out what the intention behind it was.